# Throwing exception on line called from library

Tags: c#, exception

I am building a library which contains a lot of wrappers for various bits of code I use a lot.

My library code:

```
public static void Create(string name, string location, List<string> commands)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(location))
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
    }
    else
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(location, name), commands);
    }
}
```

My sample app using the library

```
AwesomeFunction.Create("Foo", "C:\\DoesntExist\\Bar", new List<string> { "List of stuff" });
```

If the directory given isn't found it throws on the line `throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();` which makes sense, but I need it to throw on the `AwesomeFunction.Create` function.

This will stop it switching to the library code if it throws, instead it will highlight the `AwesomeFunction` line in VS.

A comparable example would be throwing an exception on

```
Directory.Delete("C:\\DoesntExist\\Bar");
```

Where it will highlight that line, even though the `throw` is in the `Directory` class.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

If I copy the library to a different location i.e. C:\mylibrary it still opens the source code for it, even though I didn't reference it through a project.

Another problem I found it that when I don't add it from my projects I don't see my XML comments on the functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that by using an assembly reference instead of a project reference for the library. This way you will not have the source code of the library in the consuming project and VS will break on the `AwesomeFunction.Create` function call. That's what happens when an exception is thrown inside the `Directory.Delete` call that you provided. Since you don't have the source code of this method linked in, VS simply stops on this line and not on the actual line inside this method that threw the exception. Obviously in the exception stacktrace you get the full stack of method calls and the origin of the exception.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was still running the `Directory.Delete` code from the test. I removed the reference and added the library using Browse from VS rather than the project tab. When running my function I get a page that says the source code is unavailable. Am I adding the reference wrong?